# PHP : any way to check if an object is null and if not, call one of its method, in one line?

Tags: php, swift, null, option-type

I'm doing an application (client in Swift and server in PHP). I would like to know if there is any way in PHP to do just like in Swift sth like :

```
myInstanceOrNil?.mymethod()
```

which call my method if the myInstanceOrNil is not nil, or return nil if myInstanceOrNil is nil.

In my php server, i have to return several optional informations (for exemple maybe the user has a facebook account associated, maybe not),

```
$member = new Member($id);   

echo json_encode([ 
    "id" => $member->getId(), 
    "fbId" => $member->getFbInformationsInstanceOrNull()->getFbId()
])
```

Problem here, if `getFbInformationsInstanceOrNull()` returns null because the user has no associated fb account, it will produce an error because `null->getFbId()` does not exist. In Swift, i would just have to do :

```
$member.getFbInformationsInstanceOrNull?().getFbId()
```

How to do it easily in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `empty` for that

```
$fbId = $member->getFbInformationsInstanceOrNull();
if(!empty($fbId)){
echo json_encode([ 
    "id" => $member->getId(), 
    "fbId" =>  $fbId->getFbId()]);
}
```

if there is no id associate, the code won't execute, you might need to show some message to the user or update the business accordingly.

In case you want to pass `null` as well, you can do it like this:

```
$fbId = $member->getFbInformationsInstanceOrNull();
echo json_encode([ 
        "id" => $member->getId(), 
        "fbId" =>  empty($fbId)?null:$fbId->getId() ]);
}
```

The following values are considered to be empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)

Read more about `empty` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done **and why** it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly true, right after writing it, I went to edit it. It's always better to explain the answer with details.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo answer is good, except on point, in the question by itself no matter if the user has associated FB account or not there will be some output with user ID accordingly, and in your case there will not be any output if the user does not have associated FB account.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo not sure :) `if(!empty($fbId)){ echo json_encode(...`

Comment: I guess you are thinking in the wrong direction.  I saw your update. Actually, if `getFbInformationsInstanceOrNull` is null processing the request or encoding won't be helpul but I will still add it..let's wait for op to clarify it

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo the thing is that according to the 1st version you have posted the system assumes that all the users MUST have fb account associated, but according to the code of question and the swift 'optionals' idea it is not so